# jTweetsAnywhere in 3 columns

Tags: javascript

I tried to use the script [http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/demo/Favorite-tweets/][1] 
Nice script, but I want to display the tweets in 2 columns: tweets from the first username in the first column, tweets of the second username in the second column and tweets of the third username in the third column. Now the tweets of each username are displayed in the same column. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use use two/three separate feeds (instances of the plugin). On the other hand you could code your own tweetFeedDecorator. Please have a look at the [docs](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/#jta_documentation) and the plugin's source code.